# Why aren't these constraints working properly on iPad 9.7" and 12.9"?

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode8

I have the following view...

[image: displayed on iPhone6s/iPhone7]

The problem I have is displaying this view on iPad 12.9" and iPad 9.7" the constraints I have setup don't seem to work at all. here are the contraints

[image: contraints]

[image: more constraints]

But when displayed on iPad 9.7" this is what it looks like...
[image: view displayed on iPad 9.7"]

Where am I going wrong? What should the constraints be so that this simple view can be laid out properly on iPhone6s, iPhone7 plus, iPad 9/7" and iPad 12.7"?? I don't even care if the iPad views are perfect, just so long as all the buttons are visible so that I can get Apple to stop rejecting my app for not supporting iPad.

Comment: You have not set Universal (iPhone + iPad) type as the application devices. Without this, your app won't be having iPad support.

Comment: thanks a lot for your insight, changing my settings to "Universal" fixed the problem. Why is there even an option besides Universal if Apple won't accept an app that doesn't support all devices?? And if you post your comment as an answer I will accept it as correct

Comment: glad that it helped. Well, the reason for Apple  giving such an option is quite useful for apps which are not giving iPad support or which want only a single device support. There can be various reasons for the app to not support iPad devices maybe because earlier the project budget increased due to iPad screen xibs. , its high resolution images  and design cost. Also, I remember that the last time I checked, there was no app for Instagram on iPad, dunno why!

Comment: Ok thanks. So how could I specify that my app is not going to support iPad? I tried submitting it to the app store with only iPhone as the selected devices, and I wrote in the description "not available on iPad", but Apple rejected the app and told me I must support iPa if possible. I said it is not possible but they insisted it was and made me re-create my storyboard to work with iPad...

Comment: that's strange. I have never heard that before. Can you please share the rejection note from Apple ?

Comment: "Guideline 2.4.1 - Performance

We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad running iOS 10.3.1. Specifically, we couldn’t login your app on iPad. We were unable to input the password due to the layout for login page on iPad."

Comment: ^This was just a few days ago after submitting my app and attempting to only support iPhone. About 6 months ago I had the same issue, so I appealed to Apple and they scheduled a phone call at which point I spent 30 minutes arguing with the Apple rep telling them that I didn't have the time or money to configure the app to work properly on iPad. She refused to accept my appeal and they wouldn't let my app through until I made the required modifications to support iPad. This time I'm not even bothering to argue with them I just am going to have to make the necessary modification when I have time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143215/discussion-between-jen-jose-and-mikeg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not set Universal (iPhone + iPad) type as the supported application devices. That is why it displays iPhone screen with scaling factor 1x,2x on iPad.

[image]